# neural network in R: tfdatasets::feature_spec() on 3D Array

Tags: r, keras, neural-network

Feeding several multivariate time series in a neural network in R seems to be a hard problem for me.
As far as I can tell there are three way to do so and they all do have their pitfalls:

- A nested tibble would be the most intuitive solution for R, but it [does not seem to work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72542698/keras-in-r-nested-tibble-as-input).
- With a 3D array you have to be [careful about the ordering](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/1262).
- Converting a 3D Array in a dataset and then creating a `tfdatasets::feature_spec(.)` results in an error.

Here is a small example, which does not work at the moment:
I get the data as a nested tibble so I start from there.

```
library(magrittr)
reticulate::use_python("/usr/local/bin/python")

data <- tibble::tibble(
  Timeseires = list(
    A = tibble::tibble(
      Period = rep(0:4, each = 10),
      MeasuremntA = runif(50, 20, 30),
      MeasuremntB = runif(50, 0.001, 0.01)
    ),
    C = tibble::tibble(
      Period = rep(0:4, each = 10),
      MeasuremntA = runif(50, 20, 30),
      MeasuremntB = runif(50, 0.001, 0.01)
    ),
    B = tibble::tibble(
      Period = rep(0:4, each = 10),
      MeasuremntA = runif(50, 20, 30),
      MeasuremntB = runif(50, 0.001, 0.01)
    ),
    D = tibble::tibble(
      Period = rep(0:4, each = 10),
      MeasuremntA = runif(50, 20, 30),
      MeasuremntB = runif(50, 0.001, 0.01)
    )
  )
)

measurement.data <- data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Timeseires = purrr::map(
    .x = Timeseires,
    .f = simplify2array
  )) %>%
  .$Timeseires %>%
  simplify2array() %>%
  tfdatasets::tensor_slices_dataset()

feature.spec.measurment <- measurement.data %>%
  tfdatasets::feature_spec(.) %>%
  tfdatasets::step_numeric_column(
    tfdatasets::all_numeric(),
    normalizer_fn = tfdatasets::scaler_standard()
  ) %>%
  tfdatasets::fit()
```

It is crashing with the following [error](https://github.com/rstudio/tfdatasets/blob/main/R/utils.R#L71):

```
Error: Unable to resolve features for dataset that does not have named outputs
```

I've tried adding some names to it, bot without success.
Do you have any idea how to insert several multivariate time series in a neural network in R with keras and thus get the example to work?

---

The remainder of the example looks like this:

```
##### Data Prep for meta.data #####
meta.data <- data %>%
  dplyr::select(-Timeseires) %>%
  tfdatasets::tensor_slices_dataset()

feature.spec.meta <- meta.data %>%
  tfdatasets::feature_spec(Result ~ .) %>%
  tfdatasets::step_numeric_column(
    tfdatasets::all_numeric(),
    normalizer_fn = tfdatasets::scaler_standard()
  ) %>%
  tfdatasets::step_categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    tfdatasets::all_nominal()
  ) %>%
  tfdatasets::step_indicator_column(
    tfdatasets::all_nominal()
  ) %>%
  tfdatasets::fit()

input.measurement <- keras::layer_input(shape = c(3, 4))

lstm.out <- input.measurement %>%
  keras::layer_lstm(units = 32)

#####

input.meta <- data %>%
  dplyr::select(-Timeseires, -Result) %>%
  tfdatasets::layer_input_from_dataset()

dense.out <- input.meta %>%
  keras::layer_dense_features(feature_columns = tfdatasets::dense_features(feature.spec.meta))

#####

output <- keras::layer_concatenate(c(dense.out, lstm.out)) %>%
  keras::layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>%
  keras::layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>%
  keras::layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>%
  keras::layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

output.auxiliary <- input.measurement %>%
  keras::layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid", name = "aux_output")

model <- keras::keras_model(
  inputs = c(input.meta, input.measurement),
  outputs = c(output, output.auxiliary)
)

model %>% keras::compile(
  loss = keras::loss_binary_crossentropy,
  optimizer = "adam",
  metrics = "binary_accuracy"
)

summary(model)

history <- model %>%
  keras::fit(
    x = list(
      # tfdatasets::dataset_use_spec(meta.data, spec = feature.spec.meta),
      # tfdatasets::dataset_use_spec(measurement.data ,feature.spec.measurment)
      data %>% dplyr::select(-Timeseires, -Result),
      data %>%
        dplyr::mutate(Timeseires = purrr::map(
          .x = Timeseires,
          .f = simplify2array
        )) %>%  .$Timeseires
        %>% simplify2array()
    ),
    y = list(
      data$Result,
      data$Result
    ),
    epochs = 10,
    validation_split = 0.3
  )
```

At the moment I've chosen this Input shape because it gets the example to work at least, but it is wrong since `dim(measurement.data) = 50  3  4` and I should actually use `keras::layer_input(shape = c(50, 3))` since the number of time series (matrices) will vary within the evaluation and be the same as in training.

Comment: What is your model input shape? Have you seen the keras pre-processing layers guide? Keras pre-processing layers are the successor to the `tfdatasets::feature_spec()`. https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/new-guides/preprocessing_layers.html

Comment: I've added the remaining code for the full net in the question. Thank you for the preprocessing layers documentation. I knew about them but did not know they work in R too.